# Creating a simple window to output information ( log style ) for debugging - wxWidgets

Tags: c++

I am learning to create GUI applications with wxWidgets, and since I am still unfamiliar with many of the features and inner workings, I would like to get some information on the processes straight away.

To clarify, if I was creating a simple console application, I could simply printf/cout relevant results, flags,... of the operations to screen, which would help me debug and follow the program flow. But since I am creating a GUI application I don't have a console opened for that. That's why I would like to open, along with the main application, a separate window that would be used to output the debugging information in a log style.

What widget/control could I use to accomplish this task, that is also relatively simple to use ?

Edit: Additional info 
I am coding in C++, using wxWidgets 3.0.1 with CodeBlocks 13.12 IDE on a W7 system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wxLogDebug()` and view the output under debugger or using a tool such as [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) under Windows and just directly in the terminal from which you run the application under Unix (including OS X).

If you want to use this for something other than strictly debugging, consider using `wxLogVerbose()` and [wxLogWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log_window.html).

Answer (score 2):

How about using `OutputDebugString` with a debugger if you are on Windows 7?

If you really want to do show message in the application itself, try something like a `listbox` and rotate it for a limited number of messages.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to build your program as a console subsystem executable.

You can build a program as GUI or console subsystem executable regardless of the code.

If you absolutely don't want to do that, then you can just pipe the output of the GUI subsystem program to a console program that copies input to output. Creating a little `cat` program, or using a *nix-utilities variant, is nice for that. Or you can possibly just use `find /v ""`.

---

Here's an example Windows API level program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Well I'm starting up!" << endl;

    auto const infobox = MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND;
    MessageBox( 0, "Just click OK, OK?", "Blah!", infobox );

    cout << "Yay, I'm finished!" << endl;
}
```

Building as console subsystem (that's the default for g++) and running:

```
C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>g++ w2.cpp

C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>a
Well I'm starting up!
    Here a message box pops up. Nothing more happens until it's dismissed.
Yay, I'm finished!

C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>_
```

Building as GUI subsystem and running:

```
C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>g++ w2.cpp -mwindows

C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>a | find /v ""
Well I'm starting up!
    Here a message box pops up. Nothing more happens until it's dismissed.
Yay, I'm finished!

C:\my\pwd\examples\winhello>_
```

Note: `clog` maps to the standard error stream, so to present such output via piping you need to e.g. do `a 2>&1`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I certainly won't start such a thing, and I actually don't know what "cat" is anyway. I realize I should probably add more info to the question. I am using C++, wxWidgets 3.0.1, CodeBlocks 13.12 IDE on a W7 system.

Comment: Oh. If `foo` is your program, then when it's built as console subsystem you can just run it, and watch the `cout` or `clog` output. When it's build as GUI subsystem, run it like `foo | find /v ""`, or `foo | cat` if you have a `cat`. ;-) (That's a Unix utility, short for *catenate* which in turn is short for *concatenate*, which is its main job: it concatenates files.)

Comment: With g++, the default compiler for Code::Blocks, the usual option to select subsystem is `-mwindows` and `-mconsole`. But it might be specified (or not at all) as a linker option, like `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` and `-Wl,-subsystem,console`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. Can you please expand your answer with giving all this extra info ? Some resources showing a simple example of a program, and also how to set the compiler to build it, would be really nice. I am really looking for a simple, beginner friendly option =)